# In textview ellipsize="end" and gravity="center" not working properly

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-xml

I need the textview like this with maxline="2"

### [image]

but when I give it the gravity="center_horizontal" and ellipsesize="end" it will give me like this. the text in the second line will be hide

[image]

---

and when I give it the **gravity="center_vertical"** and **ellipsesize="end"**  it will give me much better than above one but I need the hello text in center for good look.

[image]

---

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_list_music_songname"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Hello ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_list_music_songtimeduration"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="ABC"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your layout already showing the same result what you are expecting when I copied that in my layout screen

Comment: change android:layout_width="0dp" to match_parent

Comment: your code is working fine already the way you want it to be.

Comment: ya its can't give proper output in preview screen of android studio. Sorry its my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_list_music_songname"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Hello \n ABCDEFGHIJKhhLMNOPQRSTUVW"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_list_music_songtimeduration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="ABC"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: When this text ABCDEFGHIJKhhLMNOPQRSTUVW after \n is bigger than screen width than starting text ABCD is gone or cuts.

Comment: ya its can't give proper output in preview screen of android studio. Sorry its my mistake

Comment: ok fine. then please accept the answer if it helped you in any way

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
  <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:weightSum="2"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_list_music_songname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.6"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Hello \n ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_list_music_songtimeduration"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.4"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="ABC"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
      </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -2):

Use Gravity `"center_vertical|center_horizontal"` Try this following code

```
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
```